# BackgroundUploader and HttpBaseProtocolFilter

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Is there a way to assign a `HttpBaseProtocolFilter` object to the `BackgroundUploader`?

For the moment, I use the `HttpClient` to upload some files and set some `IgnorableServerCertificateErrors` values which are needed to get the request successfully done.

Comment: Is that for testing purposes? You can add certificate to phone root certificate authorities.